# Cast object to Class who's type was passed as a parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What I want to do is:

```
- (UIView *)getView:(UIView *)recycledView withClass:(Class)myClass
{
     myClass *currentItem = (myClass*)recycledView;
     ....
}
```

I'm calling this function as follows:

```
[self getView:myView withClass:[SpecialView class]];
```

Getting a compilation error, any ideas if it's possible to achieve this?

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`.  `get` is used for a very specific role and this isn't it.

Comment: @bbum, good point - thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cast happens during compilation, so attempting to cast to a type that's determined at run time (as in an Objective-C method call) is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Casting is a compilation only operation.  You can't cast at runtime.   At runtime, you can use `isKindOfClass:` to determine class.

In general, the need for dynamic casting indicates a design problem in your code.   Specifically, you aren't leveraging either inheritance or polymorphism correctly.

For this case, you might add:

```
+ (UIView*)recyleView:(UIView*)recycledView;
```

As a method to all of your `SpecialView` classes (or it might be abstracted).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't do it.  The best you can do is cast to the declared type of myClass.  Casts do not modify the objects, they simply declare the known (after checking) type of the existing object.

And there is no advantage to casting to a dynamic type, since all the compiler and JVM checks that occur based on the cast are static.